# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Tags: postgresql

I want to do a mapping between my  postgres DB and the model of the platform on which am working.

the mapper asks me to associate model attributes with DB attributes using SELECT SQL clause.
When writing

```
SELECT "A"."attribute" or SELECT attribute FROM A;
```

it generates this error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
Position: 8
```

i tried different select clauses, however, the problem persists !!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you expect `"A"."attribute" or SELECT attribute` to achieve?

Comment: SELECT attribute. it's recommended to indicate the attribute using a select clause (SQL)

Comment: The `or SELECT` makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? If only selecting the column `attribute` from the table `A` then the following should be ok

```
SELECT attribute FROM A;
```

The error is stating that `or SELECT attribute FROM A;` is not a valid statement

Comment: I put  SELECT "A"."attribute" (as he asked me only for select clause) or I write "SELECT attribute FROM A;" but not both of them.. and in both cases the same error is displayed..

Comment: and for identifiers please, how did you explain the use of quoting?? thanks.